# Matlab c2d function gives different output than Z-transform tables

Tags: matlab, discrete-mathematics

[c2d](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/c2d.html) is used to convert a model from continuous to discrete time. The official doc states:

> sysd = c2d(sysc,Ts) discretizes the continuous-time dynamic system model sysc using zero-order hold on the inputs and a sample time of Ts.

Why is it that when I do:

```
>> s = tf('s')
>> c2d(1/s, 1)
```

I get:

```
ans =

    1
  -----
  z - 1

Sample time: 1 seconds
Discrete-time transfer function.
```

but according to Z-transform [tables](https://www.google.com/search?q=z%20transform%20table&sxsrf=ACYBGNREMKW-eBoq8JdvSlkZwIuanc67vg:1581002360707&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=3ePeMQvSto2_jM%253A%252ChN61afzWy2UHBM%252C%252Fxc%252F%252Fm%252F01712w%253Atable@en&vet=1&usg=AI4_-kTv6ZgfAGRJ5_2cBCA7flca3dsXbg&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi38-TgnL3nAhULKVAKHY_fCFwQ_h0wE3oECA0QBA&biw=1188&bih=1069#imgrc=iQsKk9O8VjcHEM) the z transform of `1/s` is

```
ans =

    z
  -----
  z - 1
```

Why this discrepancy?

Comment: What is `s`? can you define it there? does `c2d(tf(1,[1 0]),1)` give you the answer you wanted?

Comment: Edited question. `c2d(tf(1,[1 0]),1)` gives the same answer as c2d(1/s, 1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing up two separate concepts:

1. The Laplace Transform of the **continuous** step function, u(t), is `1/s`.
2. The z-transform of the **discrete** step function, u(n) is `z / (z-1)`.

Note that the continuous step function, u(t), is not the same as the discrete step function, u(n). The latter is only defined at the time instances t = n*T through sampling.

Since the Laplace domain is for continuous signals and the z-domain is for discrete signals, there is no 1-to-1 or exact conversion between the two. There are only approximate conversions to account for the effect of the sampling action on continuous signals. That is why the `c2d` command has to use various approximation methods, zero-order-hold (zoh) being the default one.

The impulse-invariant approximation method would give the result that you are looking for since it is optimized to "produce a discrete-time model with the same impulse response as the continuous time system".

```
>> s = tf('s');
>> T = 1;
>> c2d(1/s, T, 'impulse')

ans =
    z
  -----
  z - 1
```

See the [relevant documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ug/continuous-discrete-conversion-methods.html#bs78nig-6) for more details in this.

Answer (score 0):

c2d(1/s, T, 'impulse') only gives the correct answer for T=1. For T other than 1 the result is T*z/(z-1). I ignore the reason why.